# Redirect to ASPX file from .cs File

Tags: asp.net, web, httpresponse

In asp.net Website, On a WebForm, after button onclick event I am calling code behind method as below

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     MyClass obj = new MyClass();
     String res = obj.CallMe("some parameters");
 }
```

Where MyClass resides in **MyClass.cs** file.
Inside **CallMe()** :

```
public String CallMe("some parameters")
{
   String to_return ="";
   //some code : to_return="something";
   string page_name= // some code returns a name of page to redirect to
   if(page_name is null)
   { return to_return; }
   else
      //redirect to page_name;
}
```

How to redirect from .cs file since we dont have access to HttpResponse object?

Comment: Your service-class should not perform any redirects. Separate view from logic.

Comment: thanks Arthur. But if I return the name of the page to button1_click function how will i able to know that its a Name of page and not a usual returned string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class is being called from within a web page, you have access to the static `HttpContext.Current` instance in the class. Just import the System.Web namespace and call as normal:

```
using System.Web;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(HttpContext.Current.Timestamp.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if(HttpContext.Current != null)
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~");
```

Using the HttpContext you can get the current request, response etc. However be careful to always check to ensure the current context is not null, especially if you are calling from your business layer classes.

[ASP.Net Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1666153.aspx)